# JasperReport text not showing in rtf

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm trying to generate a Rtf from a jrxml.
When I generate a pdv everithing works fine but when I try to export it to rtf the text simply disappear.
I've tryied a simplified version of the jrxml with only a textbox but I'm still getting the same problem. I'm missing some special parameter?

This is my test JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
   <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0" />
   <property name="ireport.x" value="0" />
   <property name="ireport.y" value="0" />
   <background>
      <band splitType="Stretch" />
   </background>
   <title>
      <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
         <staticText>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="79" />
            <textElement />
            <text><![CDATA[TEST]]></text>
         </staticText>
      </band>
   </title>
   <pageHeader>
      <band height="35" splitType="Stretch" />
   </pageHeader>
   <columnHeader>
      <band height="61" splitType="Stretch" />
   </columnHeader>
   <detail>
      <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
         <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="20" />
            <textElement />
            <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["TEST"]]></textFieldExpression>
         </textField>
      </band>
   </detail>
   <columnFooter>
      <band height="45" splitType="Stretch" />
   </columnFooter>
   <pageFooter>
      <band height="54" splitType="Stretch" />
   </pageFooter>
   <summary>
      <band height="42" splitType="Stretch" />
   </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

[UPDATE]

Here the code used for generation:

```
JRRtfExporter exporter = new JRRtfExporter();   
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();    
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
exporter.exportReport(); 
ServletOutputStream ouputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
ouputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
ouputStream.flush();
ouputStream.close();
```

Comment: The template looks right. Maybe something wrong with your code for generating report